# Pass to Value in C math

Tags: c

I am just learning C.  i am working through this problem trying to predict the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gNumber;
int MultiplyIt( int myVar );

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i; gNumber = 2;
    for ( i = 1; i <= 2; i++ )
        gNumber *= MultiplyIt( gNumber );
    printf( "Final value is %d.\n", gNumber );
    return 0;
}

int MultiplyIt( int myVar )
{
    return( myVar * gNumber );
}
```

so if you run this, the output is 512.  i am a bit confused on how the calculation is getting from the initial value of 2, then first time through the 'for' loop  it then assigns gNumber = 8.  then jumps to 512...

maybe i am missing something easy here, but as i said, i am very new to C and programing in general..

Comment: 0th=2;1st = (0th*0th*0th)=8; 2nd=1st*1st*1st=512;

Comment: the compiler will raise two warning messages about the unused parameters `argc` and `argv`.  suggest changing the main function signature to: `int main( void )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start from here:

```
gNumber *= MultiplyIt( gNumber );
```

This line contains a call to `MultiplyIt` with `myVar = gNumber`. By looking at the return value of that function, we can say that `MultiplyIt( gNumber )` is equivalent to `gNumber * gNumber`. So the line above is equivalent to this:

```
gNumber *= gNumber * gNumber;
```

or also:

```
gNumber = gNumber * gNumber * gNumber;
```

In plain words, the body of the `for`-loop replaces `gNumber` with its cube.

The loop runs two times, with `i` going from 0 to 1 (inclusive). `gNumber` is 2 initially. Putting everything together, here's what the loop is doing:

```
gNumber = 2 * 2 * 2 = 8;    /* First iteration, i = 1 */
gNumber = 8 * 8 * 8 = 512;  /* Second iteration, i = 2 */
```

Comment: Thank you! Like I said  i missed something easy

Answer (score 0):

given the following instrumented code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gNumber;
int MultiplyIt( int myVar );

int main ( void )
{
    int i;
    gNumber = 2;

    for ( i = 1; i <= 2; i++ )
    {
        gNumber *= MultiplyIt( gNumber );
        printf( "\n%s, gNumber *= MultiplyIt(): %d\n", __func__, gNumber);
    }

    printf( "Final value is %d.\n", gNumber );
    return 0;
}

int MultiplyIt( int myVar )
{
    printf( "\n%s, pasted parameter: %d\n", __func__, myVar);
    printf( "%s, global gNumber:  %d\n", __func__, gNumber);
    return( myVar * gNumber );
}
```

the output is:

```
MultiplyIt, pasted parameter: 2
MultiplyIt, global gNumber:  2

main, gNumber *= MultiplyIt(): 8

MultiplyIt, pasted parameter: 8
MultiplyIt, global gNumber:  8

main, gNumber *= MultiplyIt(): 512
Final value is 512.
```

so the first pass through the `for` loop is:

```
2*2*2 = 8
```

the second pass through the `for` loop is:

```
8*8*8 = 512
```